# FAB Icon Doesn't Fill Button

Tags: android, xml, material-design, floating-action-button

What about my layout is causing the floating action src icon not to expand to fill the button's entire view?

I thought that perhaps that `app:borderWidth="0dp"` would fix the issue but it didn't. The plus icon is still smaller than the button(the red area).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/chordButtons"
                android:orientation="vertical"  >
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Your fab is behaving as it suppose to :) Look at this material design [link](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button) . You can either choose bigger image or set fabSize to mini as workaround.

Comment: @NebojsaVuksic adding android.support.design:fabSize="0" (normal sized) didn't fix it. Can you provide code?

Comment: Value for fabSize mini is 1. Just set fabSize attribute in xml to mini.

Comment: The icon is smaller than the button in either normal or mini. Besides, I want the button to be normal sized anyway. I need to find a way to make the icon fill the entire space in the button, as seen in apps like Google calendar.

Comment: You should use [this](https://material.io/icons/#ic_add) icon instead.

Comment: @TheTechWolf Thats the winner, thanks! I'll accept this as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong icon. Your fab is behaving as it supposed to. Take a look at material [guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button).

Instead of that icon, you should use [this](https://material.io/icons/#ic_add) one to achieve similar fab design as it is in the Google Calendar app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a good method, but it works. I added this line to dimens.xml.

```
    <dimen tools:override="true"
    name="design_fab_image_size">56dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `app:useCompatPadding="false"` to `FloatingActionButton`.

**OR,**

You can use different `+` icon that has no outer circle. Use [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=add&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_add&theme=custom&color=rgb(255%2C%20255%2C%20255)) icon.

**OR,**

You can use third party library [com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)  to get your desired output.

**Here is an example:**

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    fab:fab_size="normal"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: I think i'll have to use the library, app:useCompatPadding="false" doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried with different  + icon that does not has any outer circle. Check my updated answer.